# Update param in list1<object> from list2<object> by using java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have two list of objects accounts and salaries and I need to iterate the list of objects. If the id matches I need to update the account object.

I have list1 and list2 these two objects are different object type. we need to update the object(param) in list1 with list2 object(param).

#### Example

```
if(accounts !=null && salaries!=null) { // checking for nulls
    for (Account obj1 : accounts) {// iterating objects
        for (Salary obj2 : salaries) {
            String id = ibj2.getId();
            if (id.equals(obj1.getId())) {// id checks  
                obj1.setxxxx(obj2.getxxxx());// set the value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
list1.stream().flatMap(x -> list2 .stream() .filter(y -> x.getId().equals(y.getId())));
```

Comment: // i have tried this 
        list1.stream().flatMap(x -> list2
        .stream() 
        .filter(y -> x.getId().equals(y.getId())));

Comment: In my opinion, it's no reason to rewrite this iterative code to java 8 streams, because it doesn't get you any performance benefits, but only complicate the readability.

Comment: @GolovPavel, that is unless the lists are big, in which case, parallel streaming will benefit here

Comment: @Sharon Ben Asher, ok, if the list is big, it's may be useful

Comment: @GolovPavel, have a look at my answer and tell me how's the readability

Comment: @SharonBenAsher It's nice, but in my opinion usual inner cycles is more intuitive against inner streams. I think it's matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final operation, `obj1.setxxxx(obj2.getxxxx());` requires to have both `obj1` and `obj2`. that dictates the item that is streamed from both lists

```
list1.stream()
    .forEach(obj1 -> 
        list2.stream()
            .filter(obj2 -> obj1.getId().equals(obj2.getId()))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(obj2 -> obj1.setxxxx(obj2.getxxxx()))
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `flatMap` (suggested in the comment), will produce a `Stream<Salary>`, which won't allow you do modify the corresponding `Account` instances.

You can create a `Stream` of `Account`s and their corresponding `Salary` and run `forEach` on that `Stream`:

```
accounts.stream()
        .flatMap(a->salaries.stream()
                            .filter(s -> s.getID().equals(a.getID())
                            .map(s -> new SimpleEntry<Account,Salary)(a,s)))
        .forEach(e -> e.getKey().setxxxx(e.getValue().getxxxx()));
```

Answer (score 3):

I would always suggest to create a Map since the lookup cost will decrease and it will become more readable.

```
Map<String, List<Salary>> salaryById = salaries.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Salary::getId));
accounts.forEach(a -> CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(salaryById.get(a.getId())).forEach(s -> s.setxxxx(..)));
```

In case Account Salary <-> Account is One to One you change grouping to `Collectors.toMap(..)`